# When I was testing a contract using ethers V6, I tried to read events from a transaction receipt and got an error

Tags: events

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

const main = async () => {
  const rsvpContractFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Web3RSVP");
  const rsvpContract = await rsvpContractFactory.deploy();
  
  await rsvpContract.waitForDeployment();
  console.log("Contract deployed to:", await rsvpContract.getAddress());


  const [deployer, wallet1, wallet2] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  let deposit = hre.ethers.parseEther("1");
  let maxCapacity = 3;
  let timestamp = 1718926200;
  let eventDataCID =
    "bafybeibhwfzx6oo5rymsxmkdxpmkfwyvbjrrwcl7cekmbzlupmp5ypkyfi";

  let txn = await rsvpContract.createNewEvent(
    timestamp,
    deposit,
    maxCapacity,
    eventDataCID
  );

  let txReceipt = await txn.wait(1);

  console.log(
    "New event created:",
    txReceipt.events[0].event,
    txReceipt.events[0].args
  );

  let eventId = txReceipt.events[0].args.eventId;
  //console.log("Event ID:", eventId);

  // 测试回复事件
  txn = await rsvpContract.createNewRSVP(eventId, { value: deposit });
  txReceipt = await txn.wait(1);
  console.log(
    "RSVP created:",
    txReceipt.events[0].event,
    txReceipt.events[0].args
  );

  txn = await rsvpContract
    .connect(wallet1)
    .createNewRSVP(eventId, { value: deposit });
  txReceipt = await txn.wait(1);
  console.log("RSVP created:", txReceipt.events.event, txReceipt.events.args);

  // 确认都出席了
  txn = await rsvpContract.confirmAllAttendee(eventId);
  txReceipt = await txn.wait(1);
  txReceipt.events.forEach((event) => {
    console.log("RSVP confirmed:", event.args.attendeeAddress);
  });

  // 模拟10年之后
  await hre.network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [15778800000000]);

  txn = await rsvpContract.withdrawUnclaimedDeposits(eventId);
  txReceipt = await txn.wait(1);
  console.log(
    "Deposits withdrawn:",
    txReceipt.events[0].event,
    txReceipt.events[0].args
  );
};

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the whole error. This error can occur due to number of mistakes.